# PHP Session Save Error

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-state

Could anyone possibly have the trick of getting around this error :

"Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct"

all session data cannot be set or read or created  anew.

Here is my php.ini snippet:

```
[Session]

session.save_handler = files

session.save_path = /home/oyugik/php/session


session.use_cookies = 0


;session.cookie_secure =

session.use_only_cookies = 1

session.name = PHPSESSID

session.auto_start = 0

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

session.cookie_path = /

session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly = 

session.serialize_handler = php

session.gc_probability = 1

session.gc_divisor = 100

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

session.bug_compat_42 = On

session.bug_compat_warn = On

session.referer_check =

session.entropy_length = 0

session.entropy_file =

;session.entropy_length = 16

session.cache_limiter = nocache

session.cache_expire = 180

session.use_trans_sid = 0

session.hash_function = 0

session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

Please help I have spent more than enough hours working on this

Comment: Does your server have access to that folder. I mean is the service running as oyugik ?

Comment: yes it is running as a service

Answer (score 0):

what permissions has folder /home/oyugik/php/session ? it must be 777, or at least user that is currenty used for run your PHP code must have write and read permissions. For example in debain standart configuration popular webserver apache+mod-php user named www-data, as I remember for CentOS user named apache

Comment: Hey it was a PHP 5.5.5 issue rather a bug

Comment: In PHP 5.5.5 one has to exclusively add the save path that apache is to use to store session info

Answer (score 0):

You should have write permission to the session_save_path which is /home/oyugik/php/session.
To do this you have to run

```
chmod 777 /home/oyugik/php/session
```